# How to get the user input using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have 16 different powershell scripts which install applications. How can I create a single batch file to ask for user input for selecting the powershell script to run?

Example:

I want to install only one application, so the batch script will ask for an input and I will type `visualstudio`. It will then run the appropriate powershell script to install Visual Studio.

```
SetLocal
    @echo on   
    :menu   

CHOICE /C VCNE /M "[V]isualStudio, [N]otePad, [c]hrome, [E]xit" 
    set answer=%CHOICE%
    if /i "%answer:~,1%" EQU "V" goto visualstudio
    if /i "%answer:~,1%" EQU "C" goto chrome
    if /i "%answer:~,1%" EQU "N" goto notepad
    if /i "%answer:~,1%" EQU "E" goto Exit


    :chrome
    C:
    cd\
    cd PowerShell
    powershell -file Chrome.ps1
    goto Menu

    :visualstudio
    C:
    cd\
    cd PowerShell
    powershell -file visualstudio.ps1
    goto Menu

    :notepad
    C:
    cd\
    cd PowerShell
    powershell -file visualstudio.ps1
    goto Menu

    :Exit
    exit
```

Comment: From the prompt, type `choice /?` which will give you all the flexibility you appear to require - and all single-key.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. tried the same but it goes to :chrome whatever the input is,

Comment: Try editing your modified code into your question so we can see and possibly fix what you are using.

Comment: It's because `answer` is empty, so you fall into the `:chrome` routine; where does `%CHOICE%` come from? have you read the help of the `choice` command that appears when typing `choice /?` into a command prompt window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
CD /D "C:\Files" 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -force
powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
:List
CLS
set /A count=0
set choice=
for /R %%i in (*.ps1) do (
if not "%%~nxi" == "%~nx0" (
set /A count+=1
echo !count!: %%~nxi
set exe[!count!]=%%i
set choice=!choice!!count!
)
)
set /P EXENUM="Enter service number to INSTALL: "
set EXECUTABLE=!exe[%EXENUM%]!
echo running %EXECUTABLE%
pause
PowerShell -File "%EXECUTABLE%"
Pause
GoTo List
```

Comment: This gives the exact result , no matter about the file numbers

Comment: this saves my entire time of execution and works like a charm, i have edited the code as per my requirements

Answer (score 1):

The following example should create the menu at run time:

It works by searching the `C:\Files` directory for the `.ps1` files and setting variables for use with the `Set /P` and `PowerShell` commands.

```bat
@Echo Off
CD /D "C:\Files" 2>Nul || Exit /B
If Not Exist *.ps1 Exit /B
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:Menu
ClS
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('"Set MO[ 2>Nul"') Do Set "%%A="
Set "i=0"
For %%A In (*.ps1) Do (Set /A i+=1
    Set "MO[!i!]=%%A"
    Echo !i!. %%~nA)

:Retry
Set "MO[S]="
Set /P "MO[S]=Select an item number or press Enter to quit " || Exit /B
If Not Defined MO[%MO[S]%] GoTo Retry
Echo=PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "!MO[%MO[S]%]!"
Pause
GoTo Menu
```

Notes:
The above example will just show you the intended command. If you are satisfied with the output, delete the penultimate line and remove `Echo=` from the line above it to actually run the selected powershell script.

*It is obviously important that the names of your scripts are distinct enough to be clear to the end user what they are selecting.*

*You can modify:
Target directory, on line `2` (currently `C:\Files`)
Executable file extension, on lines `3` & `10` (currently `.ps1`)
Selection prompt message, on line `16` (currently `Select an item number`)
Command to run, on line `18` (currently `PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File`)*

Comment: this output is absolutely fine , and  testing the script, how can i have the explanation of the commands which you used , i understand only basics like echo, i am confused on %%~nA, is there any way to know about the mechanism ? thank you

Comment: You can enter each command used at the command prompt followed by `/?` and read the usage information. Other than that, I'm afraid you'll have to learn from trying things yourself and external resources, there are many sites dedicated to scripting in whichever language you prefer.

Comment: yes i can able to see the explanation for all the commands, but not exactly for the lines 7 and 9, and also i want to install some redistribute file  before exit the code. i did tried added the command at last but it didnt worked, i want if user click on exit then it should this file and then exit, is there any possibility ?

Comment: `For` is one of the commands you'll take a while to get used to, it will however be used in almost every script you'll write. Take your time and don't worry, it'll probably take you some time to get it. If however you think you can bypass the leg work and expect me to teach you this scripting language, as part of my answer, then you're unfortunately going to be disappointed.

Comment: Thankyou so much, I have one issue if i have more than 8 files the script is automatically exiting and how can  i insert the code for process the file after the enter pressed, Yes, you are right thanks for the valuable comments. i will start learn the scripting it is really interesting.

Comment: only one issues is it shows the ERROR: Duplicate choices are not allowed if i have more then 9 files, do you want me to raise one more question

Comment: Yes my code was only to highlight a dynamic method for creating a menu, the implementation I used was only designed to work with up to `9` files. The `Choice` command `/C` option is currently accepting only single digit integers which means after `9` you cannot continue because it doesn't know the difference between the integer `10` and the two integers `1` followed by `0`. If we take a look at this, `Choice /C 12345678910111213141516` you can clearly see that after 9 all entries other than `0` would be duplicates and therefore a problem.

Comment: Yes i saw the options in command prompt, but i have totally 29 .ps1, can we insert /T in your code to get rid of the default choice?

Comment: To remove the restriction within `Choice /C`, I have updated the code to allow for working with a greater number of items by reverting to the `Set /P` method in your posted snippet; please feel free to try it.